# File upload and display in angular-possible?

Tags: node.js, angular

Just a theoretical question here-
Is it possible to allow a user to upload an img to the angular assets folder via the use of node.js?
And then display it to the user once uploaded?
Would the file system npm package help here? Or should a different package be used?

Comment: Please try to avoid asking questions like ‘is it possible’. It would be better for you to ask more specific questions on a problem you may have encountered instead.

Comment: Alright, will do in the future, sorry

Comment: It’s OK. As far as I know you may be able to achieve this with the Express framework.